# Resize child controls inside a Tab of Notebook - Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to resize the entire window including controls on a tab inside a notebook. See below code, an anyone tell what am i missing ?

I have tried a couple of things, putting grid inside a grid and some other attempts.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Playground")

#notebook
_notebook1 = Notebook(root)
_tab1 = Frame(_notebook1)
_notebook1.add(_tab1, text = "Tester", sticky = "e")
#_notebook1.grid(sticky=E+W+N+S)
#_tab1.grid(sticky=E+W+N+S)
_notebook1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

_startBtn = Button(_tab1, text="start")
_startBtn.grid(sticky=E+W)

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# _tab1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# _tab1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# _notebook1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# _notebook1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's not clear what you'r trying to do. There is only on control `Button(...`, why should it `resized`?

Comment: I have added button just for illustration purpose. My objective is that, when I resize the entire application, my tabs and all controls within the tabs in the notebook should also resize. At present the resize action stops at Notebook and controls within the tab don't resize

Comment: It's not helpfull if you repeat what you already wrote. Still got not what you want to do?? Try to answer my Question: **Why should the `Button` resize?

Comment: Relevant [tkinter-button-expand-using-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073534/tkinter-button-expand-using-grid)