# Tkinter button expand using grid

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I'm new to coding, just learning Python. I searched for answers but could not find one.

I'm trying to make a calculator for learning purposes, but I cannot make the bottom `keyboard frame` expand, or `buttons` inside expand to match the borders of the root window

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import  *

# main window configuration
root=Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
# main window frames

topmenu=Frame(root,padx=5,pady=5)
display=Frame(root,padx=5,pady=5)
keyboard=Frame(root,padx=5,pady=5,bg="red")

topmenu.grid(row=0,column=0)
display.grid(row=1,column=0)
keyboard.grid(row=2,column=0)




# topmenu widgets

# display widgets

#keyboard widgets
 #  prima riga
percentagebutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="%")
squarerootbutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="√x")
squarebutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="x²")
inversebutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="1/x")

percentagebutton.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='EWNS')
squarerootbutton.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='EWNS')
squarebutton.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='EWNS')
inversebutton.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky='EWNS')

#   seconda riga
resetbutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="C")
deletebutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="←")
divisionbutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="÷")


resetbutton.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky='EWNS')
deletebutton.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='EWNS')
divisionbutton.grid(row=1,column=3,sticky='EWNS')


#   terza riga

sevenbutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="7")
eightbutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="8")
ninebutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="9")
moltiplicationbutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="X")

sevenbutton.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky='EWNS')
eightbutton.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='EWNS')
ninebutton.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky='EWNS')
moltiplicationbutton.grid(row=2,column=3,sticky='EWNS')
#   quarta riga
fourbutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="4")
fivebutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="5")
sixbutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="6")
minusbutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="-")

fourbutton.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky='EWNS')
fivebutton.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky='EWNS')
sixbutton.grid(row=3,column=2,sticky='EWNS')
minusbutton.grid(row=3,column=3,sticky='EWNS')






#   quinta riga
onebutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="1")
twobutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="2")
threebutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="3")
plusbutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="+")

onebutton.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky='EWNS')
twobutton.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky='EWNS')
threebutton.grid(row=4,column=2,sticky='EWNS')
plusbutton.grid(row=4,column=3,sticky='EWNS')


#   sesta riga
signbutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="±")
zerobutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="0")
commabutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text=",")
resultbutton=Button(keyboard,padx=5,pady=5,text="=")

signbutton.grid(row=5,column=0,sticky='EWNS')
zerobutton.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky='EWNS')
commabutton.grid(row=5,column=2,sticky='EWNS')
resultbutton.grid(row=5,column=3,sticky='EWNS')



root.mainloop()
```

Here is an image of my calculator how it currently is:

[image: Another image to explain]

How do I make the `keyboard frame` and `buttons` resize to match the borders of the root window?

Comment: what do you want it to do? is the keyboard supposed to expand to fill the whole window?

Comment: Please do not add nonsense to questions in order to defeat the minimum length filter. There is always more detail that can be added.

Comment: @BryanOakley  almost, I'd like to have the keyboard fill the whole "keyboard" frame (the frame on the bottom)

Comment: @halfer I'm sorry :(, but i really didn't know what to add :( . I can add more detail when asked cause i'm not an expert programmer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Question**: Tkinter button expand using grid

[TkDocs: The Grid Geometry Manager Handling Resize](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html#resize)

---

> You are configure only the `root` to grow:
>
> ```
> root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
> root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
> ```

You have to configure the `keyboard` frame also to **grow if there is extra room**, add:

```
keyboard.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
keyboard.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

You have to configure **every** `keyboard row/column` with `weight=1`.

> You don't set the `keyboard` frame to expand
>
> ```
> keyboard.grid(row=0,column=0)
> ```

change to

```
keyboard.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=NSEW)
```

---

Working example:

```
root=Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
keyboard=Frame(root,padx=5,pady=5,bg="red")
keyboard.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=NSEW)

for row, row_buttons in enumerate([['%', '√x', 'x²', '1/x'], ["C", "←", "÷"]]):
    keyboard.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)
    for col, text in enumerate(row_buttons):
        keyboard.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)
        Button(keyboard, padx=5, pady=5, text=text).grid(row=row, column=col, sticky='EWNS')
```

[image]

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - TkVersion: 8.6***