# How should I use Tkinter buttons without oversize?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I am trying to draw a chessboard, but last elements are oversized. How can I solve this?

```
from tkinter import *

Form = Tk()
Form.title("H")
size = 50
arr = [[Button(Form, width=size, height=size) for j in range(8)] for i in range(8)]
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
            arr[i][j].configure(bg='white')
        else:
            arr[i][j].configure(bg='black')
        arr[i][j].place(x=i * size, y=j * size)
Form.mainloop()
```

[Launch result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKTJs.png)

Comment: Use a `tkinter.Canvas` instead of all of the buttons. It is way easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `width` and `height` keyword arguments when placing the buttons:

```
from tkinter import *

Form = Tk()
Form.title("H")
Form.geometry("400x400")
size = 50

arr = [[Button(Form, width=size, height=size) for i in range(8)] for j in range(8)]

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        color = 'black' if (i+j) % 2 else 'white'
        arr[i][j].configure(bg=color)
        arr[i][j].place(x=i*size, y=j*size, height=size, width=size)

Form.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: screenshot of what's displayed]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
size = 5
arr = []
for i in range(8):
    root.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
    for j in range(8):
        root.grid_columnconfigure(j, weight=1)
        if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
            bg = "white"
        else:
            bg = "black"
        button = Button(root, bg=bg)
        button.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="news")
        arr.append(button)
root.mainloop()
```

I change it so it uses `.grid` instead of `.pack`. That allows me to use `row=i, column=j` which is way simpler than what you did. Also copying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53079377/11106801) I was able to make the buttons expand to fit the window. I suggest that you create a frame for all of those buttons. Also it will be way easier if you used a single `tkinter.Canvas` instead of 64 `tkinter.Button`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

arr = [[Button(root) for j in range(8)] for i in range(8)]
for i in range(8):
    Grid.columnconfigure(root, i, weight=1, minsize=25)
    Grid.rowconfigure(root, i, weight=1)
    for j in range(8):
        Grid.columnconfigure(root, j, weight=1, minsize=25)
        Grid.rowconfigure(root, j, weight=1)
        if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
            arr[i][j].configure(bg='white')
            arr[i][j].grid(row= i, column= j, sticky= N+S+E+W)
        else:
            arr[i][j].configure(bg='black')
            arr[i][j].grid(row= i, column= j, sticky= N+S+E+W)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: instead of `Grid.columnconfigure(root, ...)` you can use `root.grid_columnconfigure(...)`